# double free or corruption while deleting an object (another one...)

Tags: c++, free, glibc

The code below move the an element to top of an array

```
for ( i = j; i > 0; i-- ) {
  myBlk *tmp = blks[i];
  blks[i] = blks[i-1];
  blks[i-1] = tmp;
  delete tmp;
}
```

as the execution reaches `delete tmp`, I get:

```
*** glibc detected *** double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fffd556ad10 ***
```

If I remove that statement, there is no problem. But I don't want memory to leak...

Comment: Why are you deleting anything to move an element?

Comment: I am not deleting everything. A pointer is created in a loop and at the end of loop, i delete that.

Comment: You only call delete when there is memory allocation - which you don't have in this case. Copying a pointer isn't allocating memory. So just get rid of the `delete`.

Comment: I think when you delete `tmp`, you also delete `blks[i]` and/or `blks[i-1]` due to shallow copy...

Comment: Within your loop you are calling delete j times, all on the same pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting comment to answer.

It seems that you are confusing a memory allocation with a pointer copy. In your loop, you are not doing any memory allocation. You are just copying a pointer - which does not allocate memory.

So you should get rid of the `delete`:

```
for ( i = j; i > 0; i-- ) {
  myBlk *tmp = blks[i];
  blks[i] = blks[i-1];
  blks[i-1] = tmp;
}
```

`delete` is only called when there is memory allocation - which you have none of. (none inside the loop at least)

Comment: but we can assume his array / vector is full of pointers that must be deleted.

Comment: @CashCow Correct, clarified answer.

Answer (score 2):

`tmp` is just pointing to an existing element of the array. You have not allocated `tmp` via `new`. So there is no need to delete `tmp`. I am assuming that the original array elements are allocated and freed in somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks very, very odd.

My guess (based on your comment that "A pointer is created in a loop and at the end of loop, i delete that.") I suspect that the `delete` is superfluous.

When you call `delete tmp`, this frees `blks[i-1]`, since both `tmp` and `blks[i-1]` point to the same memory. If you expect that at the end of the loop `blks` continues to contain valid pointers, then the `delete` is certainly superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the same element every time?

You move the deleted element to what was i-1 then decrement i.